# trouble using systemd for autostart in Python/Tkinter on Beaglebone

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, systemd

I am unable to enable a systemd autostart service for a python script on the Beaglebone running Debian Jessie. I am using Tkinter in my script. Here is my unit file code:

```
[Unit]
Description=Startup OQY

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/debian/oqy
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python oqy.py
SyslogIdentifier=oqy

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and here is the status error

```
● oqy.service - Startup OQY
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/oqy.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-04-06 16:40:35 UTC; 2min 58s ago
  Process: 10739 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python oqy.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 10739 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 06 16:40:35 beaglebone oqy[10739]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 06 16:40:35 beaglebone oqy[10739]: File "oqy.py", line 270, in <module>
Apr 06 16:40:35 beaglebone oqy[10739]: main()
Apr 06 16:40:35 beaglebone oqy[10739]: File "oqy.py", line 252, in main
Apr 06 16:40:35 beaglebone oqy[10739]: root = tk.Tk()
Apr 06 16:40:35 beaglebone oqy[10739]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1813, in __init__
Apr 06 16:40:35 beaglebone oqy[10739]: self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
Apr 06 16:40:35 beaglebone oqy[10739]: _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
Apr 06 16:40:35 beaglebone systemd[1]: oqy.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 06 16:40:35 beaglebone systemd[1]: Unit oqy.service entered failed state.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** Systemd services configure system services. The GUI has to wait until the display server and display manager have started, so I shouldn't be using systemd at all.

Comment: Search for this error: it looks like it's the root of your problem. There are many answers on this site and others about this: `no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote above, systemd services configure system services. The GUI has to wait until the display server and display manager have started, so systemd can't load a GUI.

Instead, write a file to /etc/xdg/autostart like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=sudo /usr/bin/python /home/debian/oqy/oqy.py
Name=oqy
Comment=Startup OQY on load
```

Comment: This actually solved my problem after being through init.d/rc.local/systemd/systemctl stuff.